# Simple pipeline status in dashboard

Tags: azure-devops

(I'm an azure-devops noob, so excuse ignorant questions)

I'm setting up lots and lots of pipelines on azure devops, and I'd quite like a simple dashboard icon that simply says the latest status...i.e. running, failed succeeded.
Jenkins has a red/green/grey spinning ball sort of graphic.
The pipeline history build history, says too much, is quite big (I'd quite like the dashboard to have 10's if not > 100 widgets), and doesnt show that a pipeline is actually running.

---- edit ----

Actually the pipeline page itself is almost better, but ideally I'd just have a dashboard with 20 x 10 icons all green/red/grey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through all widget extensions about pipelines, but didn't find an extension that fits your needs perfectly.

As a substitute, there is an extension called [Build Traffic Lights](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=4tecture.BuildTrafficLights). It shows the latest status of **one** build definition as a traffic light. So if you want to use it, you need to create multiple widgets.

[image]

If you are not satisfied with this approach, you can go to this [search results](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=widget&target=AzureDevOps&category=Azure%20Pipelines&sortBy=Relevance) to find out if there is a widget more suitable for your requirements.

Comment: this one seems better https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=heymrcarter.ProjectTile...but thanks I didn't know you could just install new widgets like this